# Tokyo Metro puzzle

Tags: riddle, visual

A riddle based on [the Tokyo Metro subway map](https://www.tokyometro.jp/library_in/en/subwaymap/pdf/rosen_en_1803.pdf)

```
Two stations east of a cone near Harajuku,
Follow the exclusive purple near here.
One more north, one more southeast,
What is the station I am currently now?
```

Here is a hint:

> "Cone" means "koen", which is Japanese for "park".

Another hint:

> The mystery station is **not** on the Hanzomon line.

Last hint:

> The mystery station is on the **Tozai Line**.

I will be posting the answer at approximately 17:30 UTC, if no one makes it.

Comment: Can the solution to this problem be achieved only by traveling along the subway routes, or is it intended that we leave the subway system and walk at some points?

Comment: For the "exclusive," think "monopoly" and "only". And it's only by travelling around the subway routes.

Comment: I posted another hint. Sorry for busting your hopes, but the mystery station is close to both of your guesses.

Comment: "*I will be posting the answer at approximately 17:30 UTC, if no one makes it*" - why such a rush? Some riddles go unsolved for weeks or months before somebody figures out the answer. You've posted on a weekend, which is always a quiet time that many users aren't online. Give it time and patience.

Comment: I agree with Rand. Also @TzuLi I've updated my answer.

Comment: Oh, oops. And btw somebody already found the answer.

Comment: Oh, yep, I'm late. Oh, well. Nice puzzle!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two stations east of a cone near Harajuku

> From Harajuku on the Yamanote Line, nearby is the Yoyogi-Koen (C02). East find the Gaiemmea station (G03).

Follow the exclusive purple near here

> Relatively near here is the Exclusive Purple: Hanzomon station (Z05)

One more north, one more southeast.

> From Hanzemon (Z05) north to Kudanshita (Z06), then southeast to Takebashi (T08).

What is the station I am currently now?

> Answer: **Takebashi** (T08)

Answer (score 2):

The cone referenced is

> Yoyogi-koen, as hinted at in the hint. This is in the bottom-left quadrant of the map along the green (Chiyoda) line, just above Shibuya, which is in large, bold text. Harajuku is nearby (to the right of Yoyogi).

Take two stations east along the

> green (Chiyoda) line to Omote-sando, which is a station containing both the green (Chiyoda) and purple (Hanzomon) lines.

Continue along the purple line until

> you reach the Hanzomon station, the only station to solely carry the purple (Hanzomon) line.

From there,

> One station north (To Kudanshila) and one station southeast (along the light blue Tozai line, per your hint) leads us to the **Takebashi** station, the final station.

Comment: Umm... I meant something else. Please reread "*exclusive* purple"

Comment: By the way, you're pretty close. Just it's a little off.

Comment: OK, thanks for letting me know @TzuLi . I may need a hint as far as "exclusive".

Comment: I added some more hints. Please check them out.

Answer (score 2):

Two stations east of a cone near Harajuku,

> By the hint, the cone is Yoyogi-koen, this might be close to Omote-sando station. Two stations east of this is Nagatacho.

Follow the exclusive purple near here.

> We follow the purple line further to get to Hanzomon station, where the purple line is the only line passing through, further again and we get to Kudanshita station.

One more north, one more southeast,

> We keep going until there is a north and then a southeast directional station in order; the next station after Kudanshita is indeed north (Jimbocho), and the station after that is indeed southeast of Jimbocho (Otemachi).

What is the station I am currently now?

> Are we therefore at Otemachi station?

Comment: Don't forget; you can switch lines!

Comment: I added some more hints. Please check them out.

Comment: El-Guest, since Nick got it first, I'll accept Nick's answer, but +1 for figuring out the hints!