# Tokyo Metro puzzle #2

Tags: riddle, visual

This is similar to [the previous one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80144/tokyo-metro-puzzle), however they are independent. The map is [here](https://www.tokyometro.jp/library_in/en/subwaymap/pdf/rosen_en_1803.pdf).

Here is the riddle:

```
From the best of interchanges
Lies a station you must seek
To the East-West you must go

Don't be grumpy, be positive!
The Japanese bridge'll be waiting for you.
Now take the route to the gold
Till you descend upon the loop.

Now which station are you at? Check!
It should be on the loop, I say.
And it should be near a JR line.

Good luck during your Metrosurfing!
```

**Hint:**

> In Japanese, "Japan" is "nihon" and "bridge" is "bashi."

Comment: hey it's a fun concept, I will think of doing one with another map :)

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, a response to the answerer to help steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

From the best of interchanges. Lies a station you must seek

> *Otemachi (T09)* station has the most lines coming together in a single station. So I will start from here.

To the East-West you must go

> At the Otemachi station there is the sky blue *Tonzai line* connecting. This is the only line connecting at this station that stretches for the far west (Nakano T01) of the city to the far east (Nishi Funabashi T23).

Don't be grumpy, be positive! 
The Japanese bridge'll be waiting for you.

> From Otemachi station (T09) I follow the Tonzai line in the positive direction to *Nihombashi* (T10). Nihombashi can be translated as "Japanese Bridge.")

Now take the route to the gold.

> To reach the gold-colored *Yurakucho* line from Nihombashi, **in a positive way**, I will first continue following the sky blue Tonzai line in a positive direction from Nihombashi (T10) to Monzen-nakacho station (T12), then transfer to magenta Oedo line and travel up from Monzen-nakacho station (E15) to Tsukishima station (E16) which connects to the gold *Yurakucho* line.

Till you descend upon the loop.

> The loop line in the Tokyo railway system is the Yamanote Line (JY). From Tsukishima station (Y21) I will follow the Yurakochu line and go in a negative direction, so descend to the *Yurakucho* station (Y18), which connects to the  Yamanote loop.

Now which station are you at? Check! It should be on the loop, I say. And it should be near a JR line.

> I am now at the **Yurakucho** station (Y18), which is on the Yamanote loop. Which is only one station away from the *Keiyo* Line.

Comment: Ehh... Hint hint... "be **positive**" means that you + not -.

Comment: @Tzu Li, I reconsidered my use of the word positive and changed part of the route. I hope I solved the riddle using this the interpretation of the riddle now.

Comment: Oops, I screwed up. What I meant "gold" was actually "yellow."

Comment: In case the orange-colored Ginza Line is meant, I would say descending upon the Yamanote-loop from the Nihombashi station (G11) happens at Shimbashi (G08) .

Answer (score 1):

```
From the best of interchanges
Lies a station you must seek
To the East-West you must go


Don't be grumpy, be positive!
The Japanese bridge'll be waiting for you.
```

> Otemachi (T09) serves at least (**best**) 5 lines. Looks like a great choice. Tozai (To means **East** and zai means **West** in Japanese) line towards east takes you to Nihombashi (T10) (**Japanese bridge**). T10 = T9 **+** 1 (**Positive**)

```
Now take the route to the gold
```

> **Gold** means Gin in Japanese. Taking Ginza or G line in Ginza direction.

```
Till you descend upon the loop.
```

> First station that meets a loop line in this direction is Shimbashi (G08) (**descend** from G10 to G08) and the loop is Yamanote line.

```
Now which station are you at? Check!
It should be on the loop, I say.
And it should be near a JR line.
```

> I am at Shimbashi (G08) station which is on Yamanote loop and near JR Shimbashi station.