# Another subway puzzle

Tags: riddle, visual, language

Inspired from [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80148/tokyo-metro-puzzle-2), here's my metro puzzle

> From Mickey's home you've started
> As Caesar would say: "nojk vo gpbypiph novodji"
> You then took the lower-rainbow-line
> Missed your appointment with Tutankhamun
> Ended up eating cakes
>
> You then took south to salute the Sun-King
> Your way to the east leaded you to Mario's gate
> You finally took north
> Ended up with small guys
>
> Where you at?

To help you, you will need [this map](https://www.ratp.fr/sites/default/files/plans-lignes/Plans-essentiels/Plan-Metro.1542892915.pdf)

Comment: You should add the visual tag if it involves maps; I've added it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The answer is:**

> Les Gobelins

**How I got there:**

From Mickey's home you've started

> Start at Marne-la-Vallée (Mickey's home = Disneyland)

As Caesar would say: "nojk vo gpbypiph novodji"

> decode "nojk vo gpbypiph novodji" to "stop at lugdunum station"
>  Lugdunum = Lyon, therefore stop at Gare de Lyon

You then took the lower-rainbow-line

> take the purple line

Missed your appointment with Tutankhamun

> Egyptian pharaoh -> drive by the station Pyramides

Ended up eating cakes

> Madeleine = french cake

You then took south to salute the Sun-King

> take the green line to Porte de Versailles (Ludwig XIV. = sun king)

Your way to the east leaded you to Mario's gate

> take the orange line to Porte d’Italie (Mario = Italian name)

You finaly took north

> take the pink line to the north

Ended-up with small guys

> small guys = goblins

Comment: yep! that's the answer :)