# Tokyo Metro puzzle #3

Tags: riddle, visual

Here's another Tokyo Metro puzzle, after the [first](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80144/tokyo-metro-puzzle) and the [second](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80148/tokyo-metro-puzzle-2). I'll be doing the fourth tomorrow, and the fifth will be based on the answers of all four.

By the way, the map is [here](https://www.tokyometro.jp/library_in/en/subwaymap/pdf/rosen_en_1803.pdf).

**Riddle:**

```
In the large parallel lines
Lies a big station, the ninth
On the peanut butter lines
And the cherry-colored line.

Four steps down the butter,
One step up the sea,
Walk around, don't go blue,
Two more steps until there's Jim.

From Jim's house, lime minus four,
Then go to the cherry minus one,
Plus one loop, plus three for Brown,
Now which station am I on?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the large parallel lines 
Lies a big station, the ninth 
On the peanut butter lines 
And the cherry-colored line.

> This is Ikebukuro, the 9th station on the brown line and also on the red line.

Four steps down the butter,

> 4 stops along the gold line takes us to Iidabashi

One step up the sea,

> One step up the blue line takes us to Kudanshita

Walk around, don't go blue, 
Two more steps until there's Jim.

> Jim as in Jimbocho station

From Jim's house, lime minus four,

> Assuming minus is left, we take the green line left four stops to get to Shinjuku-sanchome

Then go to the cherry minus one,

> Assuming minus is left, we take the red line left one stop to get to Shinjuku-nishiguchi

Plus one loop, plus three for Brown,

> The Oedo line is a loop, we take that one up to get to Higashi-shinjuku station. The we take three more on Brown. If we assume that plus is upwards (north), we get to Ikebukuro again.

Now which station am I on?

> You are at Ikebukuro station!

Comment: You got it! It's Ikebukuro. 'Round and 'round we go.

Comment: Yes, plus is north. Tweak your answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: I suggest you try #2. :)

Comment: Is #1 correct, @TzuLi ?

Comment: It's almost there, but you got it a little off.