# Tokyo metro puzzle #5

Tags: riddle, visual

This is based on the [first](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80144/tokyo-metro-puzzle), [second](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80148/tokyo-metro-puzzle-2), [third](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80163/tokyo-metro-puzzle-3), and [fourth](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80172/tokyo-metro-puzzle-4). It will be the finale of the series.

It relies on the answers to the previous four.

1. **Takebashi** (solved by **Nick** & Brandon_J)
2. ???
3. **Ikebukuro** (solved by **El-Guest**)
4. ???

And here's the [map](https://www.tokyometro.jp/library_in/en/subwaymap/pdf/rosen_en_1803.pdf) and the riddle:

> From the peanut butter cherry, you
>       Must go down south, and
>       Descend upon a three-line one,
>       The first one you may find.
>
> And then lies east of this station
>       Through greenleaf till gold,
>       And south we go and south we go
>       What good sakura we know!
>
> And then leave this part a-lonely
>       For you must part today,
>       And then journey to the station
>       Whose namesake isn't its.
>
> And head upon north till you find
>       An island full of soup, and
>       Go back one, and then change courses,
>       And then go to the one.
>
> And go along south for the ride
>       You won't be disappointed
>       And take a stop as soon as you see
>       That red train a-go!
>
> And part again, and part again
>       We must find one that's east-west
>       So long, farewell, M&M
>       We must find one that fits.
>
> And after that, we subtract one
>       And turn south-south-south-west.
>       And on the second step, we say
>       "Goodbye to all the zazz," for
>
> Then we descend upon fruit
>       And go back one whole space.
>       And now let's leave for the final one
>       We still have one more left, so
>
> Go to the station near the zoo
>       The one you put in to.
>       Then negatively travel along the loop we say,
>       Oh, I'm just a random space.
>
> "Go to the station that we screwed up
>       And thought it was a lid,"
>       And head East for your prize, beware
>       The taken bacon station.
>
> And stop just before you reach it
>       And go south-south-west one more stop
>       And there you have it, hooray!
>       But you need to reduce the four
>       Down to one single station,
>       That's up to you, but just remember
>       That the centroid always counts.

Comment: (It might be time for a hint here...)

Answer (score 1):

### Partial Answer ~

**First stanza**

From the peanut butter cherry, you

> Higashi-shinjuku

Must go down south, and

Descend upon a three-line one,

The first one you may find.

> Shinjuku-gyoemmae

**Second stanza**

And then lies east of this station

Through greenleaf till gold,

> Ichigaya

And south we go and south we go

What good sakura we know!

> Sakuradamon

Comment: Oops, I forgot to say that this relies on the answers to #1-#4.